# Is it possible to get motion vector from ffmpeg using cuvid decoder (h264_cuvid)

Tags: vector, ffmpeg, h.264, motion, cuvid

I wonder if is it possible to get motion vector data from the decoding of an h264 stream with ffmpeg using the h264_cuvid decoder. With the standard "h264" decoder, I can get them in the sidedata of the avframe (passing the     av_dict_set(&opts, "flags2", "+export_mvs", 0); to the avcodec_open2 function).
But what about the cuvid version? I've done a search, but with no success.
Does someone know anything about it?
Thanks